# Ajax call data issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have data from an ajax call like so:

```
[ { "id": "1", "name": "Jim", "age": "39", "address": "12 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "1", "isStudent": "1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Fred", "age": "29", "address": "13 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "1", "isStudent": "0" }, { "id": "3", "name": "Bill", "age": "19", "address": "14 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "0" }, { "id": "4", "name": "Tom", "age": "39", "address": "15 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "0", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "0" }, { "id": "5", "name": "Cathy", "age": "29", "address": "16 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "0", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "1" }, { "id": "6", "name": "Petra", "age": "19", "address": "17 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "0", "canWorkNights": "1", "isStudent": "0" }, { "id": "7", "name": "Heide", "age": "39", "address": "18 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "0" }, { "id": "8", "name": "William", "age": "29", "address": "19 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "1" }, { "id": "9", "name": "Ted", "age": "19", "address": "20 High Street, London", "hasCar": "0", "speaksForeignLanguage": "0", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "1" }, { "id": "10", "name": "Mike", "age": "19", "address": "21 High Street, London", "hasCar": "1", "speaksForeignLanguage": "0", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "1" }, { "id": "11", "name": "Jo", "age": "19", "address": "22 High Street, London", "hasCar": "0", "speaksForeignLanguage": "1", "canWorkNights": "0", "isStudent": "1" } ]
```

what I am trying to do with this data is draw out a div element but I just want specific data information for what I am trying to draw out.

```
function makeTable(data){
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
                console.log(v.age);
              tbl_body += "<spam>"+v.age+"</spam>";      
            })
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }
```

but it says v.age in undefined :(

here is my ajax call:

```
function updateEmployees(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#listings').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }
```

how would I get just the age, in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using two each functions.. why is that? You are iterating inside the object properties.. in this case you don't need that.. Try this one:

```
function makeTable(data){
   var tbl_body = "";
      $.each(data, function() {
          console.log(this.age);
          tbl_body += "<span>"+this.age+"</span>";      
      })

    return tbl_body;
}
```

Also note that I changed the `<spam>` to `<span>` .. You wrote it wrong, and I don't know what are you trying to do, but this won't make any table. Ask if you help on this.

Comment: Perfect...except i changed v.age to this.age

Comment: @user3723240 Yeap, sorry I forgot that!